# explode string at "newline,space,newline,space" in PHP

Tags: php, string, explode

This is the string I'm trying to explode. This string is part of a  paragraph which i need to split at every "newline,space,newline,space" :

```
s

 1
```

A result from textmagic.com show it contains a \n then a space then a \n and then a space.

[image]

This is what I tried:

```php
$values = explode("\n\s\n\s",$string); // 1
$values = explode("\n \n ",$string);   // 2
$values = explode("\n\r\n\r",$string); // 3
```

**Desired output:**

```
Array (
    [0] => s
    [1] => 1
)
```

but none of them worked. What's wrong here?
How do I do it?

Comment: What is the desired output here?

Comment: I've added desired output to the question. btw i reverted back some of the edit that you made because it changes the spaces and newlines in the string.

Comment: My guess is that you are dealing with Windows newlines, so the proper string would become `\n\r \n\r `, but I haven't tested it, as I'm typing this comment from my mobile

Comment: Where exactly do you think it shows in that textmagic output that it was \n? The legend explicitly says that the yellow-ish symbols are counted as _two_ characters, so that would make it much more likely that this is indeed \r\n. Plus, if you are not sure what your data actually contains, using urlencode is a quick way to get to see those “invisible” byte sequences.

Comment: There might be a problem with your interpretation of a 'newline' character, the representation of it depends on the operating system and character set encoding. So "\n" might not match the 'newline' character of your data, binary wise. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline . The screenshot of TextMagic says that the newline character in the data takes 2 bytes, which should point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `explode()` with `PHP_EOL." ".PHP_EOL." "`, which is of the format "newline, space, newline, space". Using `PHP_EOL`, you get the correct newline-format for your system.

```php
$split = explode(PHP_EOL." ".PHP_EOL." ", $string);
print_r($split);
```

Live demo at https://3v4l.org/WpYrJ

Answer (score 0):

Using preg_split() to explode() by multiple delimiters in PHP

Just a quick note here. To explode()  a string using multiple delimiters in PHP you will have to make use of the regular expressions. Use pipe character to separate your delimiters.

```
$string = "\n\ranystring"
$chunks = preg_split('/(de1|del2|del3)/',$string,-1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);

// Print_r to check response output.
echo '<pre>';
print_r($chunks);
echo '</pre>';
```

PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY  – To return only non-empty pieces.